# Is Tor really secure and anonymous when it is bankrolled by the Government which spy and snoop on it the most?

Tags: anonymity, security

After reading the [news](http://www.theverge.com/2014/7/29/5948649/tor-received-1-8-million-federal-funds-in-2014?utm_source=howtogeek&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=newsletter) I doubt the safety of mine and others who use Tor, as one side of the Government is trying to spy and snoop on it and the other side is bankrolling it. Then what prevent the two side of the same coin to join together to share their data and/or know how? In legal jargon this is called ***"conflict of interest"***

Comment: officially yes, its secure ;)

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/37433

Comment: @Jens, Dear Jens, This question is about conflict of interest by Tor. It will not help Tor to close this question.

Comment: @jens, Dear Jens, The point of conflict of interest brought up in this question will not go away by closing this question. Maybe, somebody like Arma from Tor team can be invited to provide a reasonable response to this point.

Comment: @Roya This question is just speculative and doesn't fit to the format of SE. I see no point how Tor.SE could benefit from it.

Comment: This is one of the MOST IMPORTANT QUESTIONS on this stack site and it is closed as "UNCLEAR"? Yeah, I really suppose Tor is secure and anonymous and totally transparent and unaffected by anyone despite it openly being funded by the government.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We hope and wish that it is secure, but can we prove it? Absolutely not. Let us give it the benefit of a doubt. Now there are so many zero day flaws associated with Tor, Tails, OS, browser, relays, SSL, encryption and the infrastructure of the network that you may think it may not be necessary to make a built in back door. I assume if not all, vast majority of Tor users are already known to government. If you look at it carefully, since Edward Snowden revealed the extent of government spying and snooping, every few months we hear about a zero day flaw, browser flaw, SSL flaw, relay snooping, bridge sent by unsecured email to client and more. So only the naive would believe that they are really secure. Having said that, there are very few things that even provide the level of security that Tor,Tails,JAP(JonDo), and few others will provide. Welcome to the Matrix like world.